# Telerik MVC Menu "MenuItem.Action()" renders wrong url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik MVC Menu to render my mainmenu.
Following code is the line where a certain menu item gets built up:

```
item.Add().Text("Address").ImageUrl("~/Content/Images/Icons/house.png").Action("index", "basicdata", new {basicdatatype=BasicDataType.ADDRESS});
```

I expect the url to become: `localhost/basicdata/address`
But it actually renders: `localhost/basicdata?basicdatatype=address`

I'd like to get that enum in my Controller as so:

```
public ActionResult Index(BasicDataType basicDataType)
{
     //Code here
}
```

But it doesn't work because the URL isn't in the right format. Can someone help out?

---

**EDIT:**

Even the following renders the wrong url:

```
item.Add().Text("Test").Action<BasicDataController>(o => o.Index(BasicDataType.PROJECT));
```

Comment: FYI: http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/12-05-31/kendo-ui-for-asp-net-mvc-and-the-telerik-extensions-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using areas, you have to specify that area when linking to it from outside:

```
@{ Html.Telerik().Menu()
     .Name("Menu")
     .Items(menu =>
     {
       menu.Add()
       .Text("Address")
       .Action("index",
               "basicdata",
               new { basicdatatype = BasicDataType.ADDRESS,
                     area = "basicdata" });
     }).Render();
 }
```

Comment: I just reproduced this (MVC4 and TelerikMvcExtensions 2012.1.214) and it works. Did you possibly add the route after adding the default route, which might cause the wrong route to be used?

Comment: The routes are added in the basicdata Area, and the areas are registered before the routes in global.asax. It might have something to do with the areas?

Comment: Tested some things now, and I do not have an answer for you, yet. However, it does look like areas do play a role. When the Telerik menu is defined in a view outside of the area, the link is wrong - as you wrote in your question - but if it is in the area that it links to, the link is perfect.

Comment: Updated my answer. It looks like you have to link to the area explicitly. The strongly-typed links apparently do not support that correctly: http://notherdev.blogspot.de/2012/04/strongly-typed-links-within-aspnet-mvc.html